# A* pathfinding not working with difficult obstacles

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm, a-star

I recently started making A* pathfinder so I could have good AI in my game. I made a lot of progress and the pathfinder was ready in my opinion, but when I tried it, weird things happened. I made it in a way that when the program created the path to go, the end point started moving towards the start point. It works in the way it's supposed to when the path is drawn without "difficult" obstacles, but when there is obstacles that force it to go whole different way than it wants to the problems appear... The end point didn't go to the start point completely straight but jumping around...

The picture below demonstrates when the problem happens and when doesn't.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()


class Node():
    def __init__(self, x, y, parent, color, move, end):
        if end != None:
            self.H = abs(end[0]/25 - x/25) + abs(end[1]/25 - y/25)
        else:
            self.H = 0
        self.G = 1
        self.F = self.G + self.H
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.child = []
        self.color = color
        self.move = move

        self.parent = parent

    def AddChild(self, end, current_node, nodes):
        for node in nodes[0]:
            if pygame.Rect(nodes[Closed][current_node].x + tile, nodes[Closed][current_node].y, tile, tile).colliderect(pygame.Rect(node.x, node.y, tile, tile)):
                node.color = (0, 255-self.F, 255)
                node.parent = nodes[Closed][current_node]
                nodes[Closed][current_node].child = node
                nodes[1].append(node)
            elif pygame.Rect(nodes[Closed][current_node].x - tile, nodes[Closed][current_node].y, tile, tile).colliderect(pygame.Rect(node.x, node.y, tile, tile)):
                node.color = (0, 255-self.F, 255)
                node.parent = nodes[Closed][current_node]
                nodes[Closed][current_node].child = node
                nodes[1].append(node)

            elif pygame.Rect(nodes[Closed][current_node].x, nodes[Closed][current_node].y - tile, tile, tile).colliderect(pygame.Rect(node.x, node.y, tile, tile)):
                node.color = (0, 255-self.F, 255)
                node.parent = nodes[Closed][current_node]
                nodes[Closed][current_node].child = node
                nodes[1].append(node)
            elif pygame.Rect(nodes[Closed][current_node].x, nodes[Closed][current_node].y + tile, tile, tile).colliderect(pygame.Rect(node.x, node.y, tile, tile)):
                node.color = (0, 255-self.F, 255)
                node.parent = nodes[Closed][current_node]
                nodes[Closed][current_node].child = node
                nodes[1].append(node)

        for i in range(0, len(nodes[1])-1):
            if nodes[1][0] in nodes[0]:
                nodes[0].remove(nodes[0][nodes[1][0]])



    def Draw(self, font):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y, tile, tile))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x+1, self.y+1, tile-2, tile-2))



        label = font.render((str(self.H)), True, (0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(label, (self.x+3, self.y+5))
        label = font.render((str(self.F)), True, (0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(label, (self.x+3, self.y+int(tile/2)))

    def Source(self):
        return self.parent, self



Open = 0
Closed = 1

nodes = [[], []]
current_node = 0
used_nodes = []

path = []

W = 1000
H = 950

tile = 25

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))
pygame.display.set_caption("A*")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

End = Node(500, 650, None, (255, 0, 0), False, None)
Start = Node(300, 300, None, (0, 255, 0), False, [End.x, End.y])


for i in range(0, int(H/tile)):
    for j in range(0, int(W/tile)):
        nodes[Open].append(Node(j*tile, i*tile, None, (255, 255, 255), False, [End.x, End.y]))

for node in nodes[Open]:
    if pygame.Rect(Start.x, Start.y, tile, tile).colliderect(pygame.Rect(node.x, node.y, tile, tile)):
        print(nodes[Open][nodes[Open].index(node)+1].x, nodes[Open][nodes[Open].index(node)+1].y)
        nodes[Closed].insert(nodes[Open].index(node), node)
        node.color = (0, 255, 255)
        nodes[Open].remove(node)


font = pygame.font.Font(None, int(tile/2))

A = W*tile
B = None
Break = False

Draw = False

while len(path) == 0:
    clock.tick(120)
    pygame.display.flip()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        elif e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if e.key == pygame.K_SPACE and Draw == False:
                Draw = True
            elif e.key == pygame.K_SPACE and Draw == True:
                Draw = False





            elif e.key == pygame.K_c:
                for i in nodes[Closed]:
                    if i.child == []:
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (i.x, i.y, tile, tile))
                        clock.tick(10)
                        pygame.display.flip()
                    else:
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (i.x, i.y, tile, tile))


        elif e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            for i in nodes:
                for node in i:
                    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    if pygame.Rect(x, y, 1, 1).colliderect(pygame.Rect(node.x, node.y, tile, tile)):
                        B = [node, nodes.index(i)]
                        Break = True
                    elif Break == False:
                        B = [x, y]


            if B != None:
                if Break == False:
                    nodes[Open].append(Node(int(x/tile)*tile, int(y/tile)*tile, None, (255, 255, 255), False, [End.x, End.y]))
                else:
                    nodes[B[1]].remove(B[0])

    if Draw == True:
        A = W*H*tile
        used_nodes.append(current_node)
        nodes[Open][0].AddChild(End, current_node, nodes)
        for node in nodes[Closed]:
            if node.F < A and nodes[Closed].index(node) != 0 and nodes[Closed].index(node) not in used_nodes:
                A = node.F
                current_node = nodes[Closed].index(node)
            elif current_node in used_nodes:
                current_node += 1





    for node in nodes[Closed]:
        if pygame.Rect(End.x, End.y, tile, tile).colliderect(node.x, node.y, tile, tile):
            parent, self = nodes[Closed][len(nodes[Closed])-1].Source()
            path.append(parent)
            nodes[Open].append(self)
            nodes[Closed].remove(self)
            break
    try:
        while [path[len(path)-1].x, path[len(path)-1].y] != [Start.x, Start.y]:
            parent, self = nodes[Closed][len(nodes[Closed])-1].Source()
            if parent not in path:
                path.append(parent)
            nodes[Open].append(self)
            nodes[Closed].remove(self)
    except: IndexError


    if Break == True:
        Break = False



    for i in nodes[Open]:
        i.Draw(font)

    for i in nodes[Closed]:
        i.Draw(font)

    Start.Draw(font)
    End.Draw(font)

while True:
    clock.tick(10)
    pygame.display.flip()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()


    if len(path) > 0:
        End.x = path[0].x
        End.y = path[0].y
        path.remove(path[0])





    for i in nodes[Open]:
        i.Draw(font)

    for i in nodes[Closed]:
        i.Draw(font)

    Start.Draw(font)
    End.Draw(font)
```

Picture about the problems:

[image: img]

Comment: I think it's better to post whole code in your question no matter how large it is, Because some community members may do not have access to external links

Comment: This is a very broad question. Please try to narrow it down. Please post a MVCE (minimum verifiable complete example) as opposed to the entire code.

Comment: Wikipedia has [psuedo code for this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode). (And an animation showing the "difficult" obstacle)

Comment: @SuperSaiyan I believe, it is [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007 Okay, I will check it out and see if it helps in my problem :)